# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'week' of undefined

Tags: elm

I'm getting an uncaught typeerror in elm and don't know why.

I'm decoding a json string from an api; the api is giving a list of `rostars` and each rostar has *either* a `planningId` or a `flexplanningId`. I'd like to map over the list and give each `planning` a unique `id` based either on the `planningId` or the `flexplanningId`, depending on which it has. Here's the code:

The record definition and the decoders:

```
type alias Rostar =
    { employee : Employee }


type alias Employee =
    { week : Week
    , name : String
    , id : Int
    , contractHours : Float
    }


type alias Week =
    { monday : List Planning
    , tuesday : List Planning
    , wednesday : List Planning
    , thursday : List Planning
    , friday : List Planning
    , saturday : List Planning
    , sunday : List Planning
    }


type alias Planning =
    { time : String
    , planningId : Maybe Int
    , groupId : Int
    , groupName : String
    , flex : Bool
    , employeeTimeslotId : Maybe Int
    , flexplanningId : Maybe Int
    , employeeId : Maybe Int
    , id : Maybe Int
    }


responseDecoder : Decoder (List Rostar)
responseDecoder =
    list rostarDecoder


rostarDecoder : Decoder Rostar
rostarDecoder =
    decode Rostar
        |> required "employee" employeeDecoder


employeeDecoder : Decoder Employee
employeeDecoder =
    decode Employee
        |> required "rostar" weekDecoder
        |> required "name" string
        |> required "id" int
        |> required "contract_hours" float


weekDecoder : Decoder Week
weekDecoder =
    decode Week
        |> required "monday" (list planningDecoder)
        |> required "tuesday" (list planningDecoder)
        |> required "wednesday" (list planningDecoder)
        |> required "thursday" (list planningDecoder)
        |> required "friday" (list planningDecoder)
        |> required "saturday" (list planningDecoder)
        |> required "sunday" (list planningDecoder)


planningDecoder : Decoder Planning
planningDecoder =
    decode Planning
        |> required "time" string
        |> optional "planning_id" (nullable int) Nothing
        |> required "group_id" int
        |> required "group_name" string
        |> required "flex" bool
        |> optional "employee_timeslot_id" (nullable int) Nothing
        |> optional "flexplanning_id" (nullable int) Nothing
        |> required "employee_id" (nullable int)
        |> hardcoded Nothing
```

The mapping:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        HandleFeedResponse response ->
            let
                assignPlanningId : Planning -> Planning
                assignPlanningId planning =
                    case planning.planningId of
                        Just id ->
                            { planning | id = Just (id + 10000000) }

                        Nothing ->
                            case planning.flexplanningId of
                                Just id ->
                                    { planning | id = Just (id + 90000000) }

                                Nothing ->
                                    { planning | id = Nothing }

                planningWithId : List Planning -> List Planning
                planningWithId day =
                    List.map assignPlanningId day

                mapWeek : Week -> Week
                mapWeek week =
                    { week
                        | monday = planningWithId week.monday
                        , tuesday = planningWithId week.tuesday
                        , wednesday = planningWithId week.wednesday
                        , thursday = planningWithId week.thursday
                        , friday = planningWithId week.friday
                        , saturday = planningWithId week.saturday
                        , sunday = planningWithId week.sunday
                    }

                updateResponse : List Rostar
                updateResponse =
                    List.map
                        (\r ->
                            let
                                employee =
                                    { employee | week = mapWeek employee.week }
                            in
                                { r | employee = employee }
                        )
                        response

                check =
                    Debug.log "updatedResponse" updateResponse
            in
                { model | rostar = updateResponse } ! []
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'week' of undefined
>   Blockquote

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is caused by the `let` binding of `employee` in the `updateResponse` mapping function. The label `employee` already exists, so this line is causing a recursive definition.

```elm
let
    employee =
        { employee | week = mapWeek employee.week }
```

In Elm 0.18, this is a compile error and gives you a detailed error message rather than leaving the possibility for a runtime error:

> Detected errors in 1 module.
>
> ```
> -- BAD RECURSION ------------------------------------------------------ Main.elm
> ```
>
> `employee` is defined directly in terms of itself, causing an infinite loop.
>
> ```
> 132|>                                employee =
> 133|                                     { employee | week = mapWeek employee.week }
> ```
>
> Maybe you are trying to mutate a variable? Elm does not have mutation, so when I
>   see `employee` defined in terms of `employee`, I treat it as a recursive
>   definition. Try giving the new value a new name!
>
> Maybe you DO want a recursive value? To define `employee` we need to know what
>   `employee` is, so let’s expand it. Wait, but now we need to know what `employee`
>   is, so let’s expand it... This will keep going infinitely!
>
> To really learn what is going on and how to fix it, check out:
>   https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.18.0/hints/bad-recursion.md

Prior to 0.18, I would see these types of odd "undefined" runtime errors when accidentally performing some kind of unintended recursion. In 0.18, they've added compiler checks for some of the most basic types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This may not the source of your error, 
but your employee-decoder says it needs a `rostar` variable, which contains a `week`. Is this correct? Or should it be called `week`?

Here is the code snippet:

```
employeeDecoder : Decoder Employee
employeeDecoder =
    decode Employee
--        |> required "rostar" weekDecoder -- is this correct?
        |> required "week" weekDecoder     -- what I would have expected
        |> required "name" string
        |> required "id" int
        |> required "contract_hours" float
```